# Use Laravel to refactor old, large PHP application partially over time?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

From what I've read this should be possible due to the modular nature of Laravel, but I need assurance from people with more Laravel experience:

I have a very large (500k loc) ancient PHP app. So ancient that some parts of it date from PHP3 times (ca. 2000, PHP4 was released already but PHP3 was used for backwards compatibility reasons).

Refactoring this is a huge project, and the only way to reasonably do it is in parts. Replace this part, then that part, etc. Fortunately, the "ancient" part comes in handy as no framework was used and basically every page is its own script, with a few central libraries for shared functionality.

Is it possible to spin up a Laravel app that can route new/refactored pages to the new site and everything else (wildcard if possible) to the ancient code? All data is stored in a database, so there will be no sync issues between them except for user authentication and session info.

Is it possible to get eloquent running on an ancient DB design or to refactor the DB in such a way that it works for both? There was a previous attempt to move the DB interface to Doctrine which from what I know was aborted after partial success (i.e. many DB objects are accessed through Doctrine, but there is also a lot of straight SQL code in parallel).

It's a huge mess, but the software in question is still being used and successfully so and a previous attempt to replace it with something else has already failed.

---

*additional details*:

Thanks @maiorano84 for good questions:

> First, does your legacy application have tests?

Negative on that. PHPUnit was released in 2004. At that time, this app had already been in production for four year.

> Second, are you able to get it to work on a more recent version of PHP?

Yes, the current codebase is running on PHP 5.6.33 - it has been maintained throughout the years, and a major update was made on the transition between PHP 4 and PHP 5.

Answer (score 3):

### If it runs on PHP 5.3+, you can use Instant Refactoring

I'm an author of [Rector](https://getrector.org/), a tool that can migrate huge amount of PHP files in a few seconds. E.g. upgrade PHP 5.3 to PHP 7.4, upgrade Symfony 2.8 to 4.2 or migrate from Nette to Symfony ([read the case study](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2019/02/21/how-we-migrated-from-nette-to-symfony-in-3-weeks-part-1/)).

#### 1. Install Rector

```
composer require rector/rector --dev
```

#### 2. Create `rector.php` with PHP sets, since you have old PHP code

```
// rector.php
use Rector\Core\Configuration\Option;
use Rector\Set\ValueObject\SetList;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\Configurator\ContainerConfigurator;

return static function (ContainerConfigurator $containerConfigurator): 
void {
    $parameters = $containerConfigurator->parameters();
    $parameters->set(Option::SETS, [
        SetList::PHP_52,
        // use one set at a time, as sets build on each other
        // SetList::PHP_53,
        // SetList::PHP_54,
    ]);
};
```

#### 3. Then run Rector on your code (e.g. `/src` directory)

```
vendor/bin/rector process src
```

You can also **[write your own rules](https://github.com/rectorphp/rector/#1-create-new-rector)**, so you can convert the code to Laravel/MVC approach. The idea is to write one rule, that e.g. converts 100+ files to controllers.

[Read more on Github repository](https://github.com/rectorphp/rector/).

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible? Yes.

Is it going to take a short amount of time? *Absolutely not*.

With any kind of legacy codebase, you're going to need to take the time in figuring out all of its moving parts and figuring out what portions are going to need to change in order to even be able to work on a modern platform.

The most recent version of Laravel requires PHP 7.1.3, so even attempting to just dump the entire codebase into a Laravel application is very likely going to result in failure.

First, does your legacy application have tests? These can be unit tests, integration tests, or functional tests. If not, and you want to be able to modernize your application without breaking things in the future, then you're going to want to write tests to ensure that nothing breaks as you begin upgrading. This alone can take a long time, especially with a codebase that makes it difficult to even test in the first place. Having a fully tested application will allow you to see which tests begin to fail as you start reworking your application, so this information will be extremely valuable.

Second, are you able to get it to work on a more recent version of PHP? If this code is already in production, then you're going to need to use some hardware virtualization through [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/), or better yet, containerization through [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) to get a local installation up and running without breaking your production code.

Once that's ready, then you should be able to begin refactoring. Taking entire pages of code and dumping them right into a Laravel application is not going to work straight out of the gate. You're going to want to start smaller. Find all of your moving parts, figure out what each one is responsible for, and encapsulate them in classes with the appropriate methods.

Use Composer's [PSR-4 Autoloader](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4) to help remove all of those extra `include` and `require` statements and load your new classes throughout the application.

Use a decent [Router](http://route.thephpleague.com/) to change all of your URLs into SEO-friendly paths and have a clearly defined entrypoint for all requests.

Move all of your business logic out of webroot: Create a `/public` folder in which you have just your `index.php` entrypoint and all public-facing assets (images, css, javascript, etc.). Since all requests are all being routed over to this file by this point, you should be able to process the request and return your response.

Once you get to a point where you've actually gotten the application into a system of well-defined components and modules, then migrating over to Laravel - or any other well-established framework - should be much easier.

This is going to take you a ***long*** time if you plan on doing it right. Hopefully this helps, and best of luck to you.

Comment: edited question to include answers about details. And yes I realize this is a huge project, but there's a good chance it will run for another 10-20 years.

Answer (score 0):

Refactoring is of course possible, but I have some doubts, if it is doable partially in this case. By partially here, I mean that, parts of the app will run  sometimes on old and sometimes on new code in production.

I did this once for and old project, but not as ancient and big as yours.

In my case it was custom app (without any framework) running on php 5.3 and I was converting it to Laravel 4.2.

I must admit that there are some real challenges on the path.
This is only tip of the iceberg, but I'll try to name few of them, from what I remember:

1. **PHP version compatibility** or rather incompatibility in this case. You can rewrite existing code to run on latest PHP 7 versions. That might be a lot work however - not used in the end.
2. **Routing and asset handling** - you need to check if you can modify urls so they can fit into Laravel routing engine. It may be really hard, especially if old app is using Laravel standard paths and if you don't want to break google indexing for example. I have also seen systems with custom generators for urls which were then heavily used in views. Trying to do perfect match for these routes would be a nightmare.
3. **Authentication**. Changing auth must be done in one step, cause adapting Laravel to properly work with sessions from old system (although doable) will clutter new code.
4. **Database**. You will be lucky if database is well designed, but I don't think it will be even close to Laravel Eloquent conventions. Although you can run it on Laravel without any DB schema modifications, your new code will also get bloated in your new app. This and other things can be refactored again in complete system, but it's another load of work.

Considering amount of all possible, not optimal workarounds, in order to have properly designed app (built with best practices), probably it will be better to rebuild from scratch.

Hope it helps a bit...